# Web Services extensible markup language

Tags: android, web-services

If i want connect extensible markup language   `web services` with `android` application what can i do and what the difference if i use `java-script object notation`  `web services` with `android`

Answer (score 1):

IF you want to compare `XML` and `JSON` format ( what would be better with android). Please see some points here:

1. `JSON` is both more compact and (in my view) more readable - in transmission it can be "faster" simply because less data is transferred.
2. In parsing, it depends on your parser. A parser turning the code (be it `JSON` or `XML`) into a data structure (like a map) may benefit from the strict nature of XML (XML Schemas disambiguate the data structure nicely) - however in `JSON` the type of an item (String/Number/Nested JSON Object) can be inferred syntactically.
3. If you find performance to be an issue (I'm making this suggestion because these libs make you super productive), there are mechanisms in both to allow you finer grained control. I doubt you'll have problems with performance though.
4. I can think of to use `XML` over `JSON` is when your webservice responses are huge. `JSON` usually requires the entire response to arrive before you can start parsing.

You can reach more example about them on internet, and do some android test to see the performance as well.

> Example of JSON parsing in Android you can find in this [Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android](http://androidexample.com/Restful_Webservice_Call_And_Get_And_Parse_JSON_Data-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=101&aaid=123).
>
> Example of XML parsing in Android you can find in this [XML_Parsing_Android](http://androidexample.com/XML_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=69&aaid=94).

Hopefully, it would be helpful for you!

Comment: Ok but i have another question  why in web development like php use xml somtimes  and not use json with php

Comment: it depends in different business logic of each system... xml will be input/output data from other system  what this php system need to get or send...